# Mimic radio button push (PHP, JS)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've tried to fix this problems for a week now without any success. I am a novice in this area so please bear with me.

I am using TastyIgniter, an online ordering system for food. Before you can add any items to your cart, you have to choose between Delivery or Collection. I have disabled the delivery feature as I only want people to order collection. I still have to press the 'Collection' button before I can do anything else. I need to get rid of this step.

```
// The buttons are basically radio buttons with a value of "1" and "2", where;
Delivery = 1
Collection = 2
```

After you press one of the buttons, you declare;

```
$order_type === '1' or $order_type === '2'
```

Unfortunately, order type 1 is preselected, not order type 2.

To make this easy for myself after trying to modify the model, controller and button, I am looking for a feature that mimics the push of the button so I then can hide it with CSS.

Button Inspection:

```
function() {  if (typeof this.value !== 'undefined') {
var order_type = this.value;

$.ajax({
  url: js_site_url('cart_module/cart_module/order_type'),
  type: 'post',
  data: 'order_type=' + order_type,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(json) {
    if (json['redirect'] && json['order_type'] == order_type) {
      window.location.href = json['redirect'];
    }
  }
});
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried jquery trigger()?

Comment: No, please elaborate if you want! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://api.jquery.com/trigger

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Apply this to your code if you want to simulate a click.

Comment: I have read that but how do I declare what button I want to be 'clicked'?. This is how the two button looks
https://codepaste.net/9dz8pq

Comment: You can listen for the click on the button in question, then use event.preventDefault() to prevent the button from taking its intended action.

Answer (score 0):

The event is fired from a click on the label, so this should work:

```
$('input[name="order_type"][value="2"]').parents('label').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ethan! :) Where exactly would I put this code?

Comment: Your question was how to mimic the push of a radio button, but after looking at TastyIgniter a little more it seems you can just turn off Delivery in the admin panel. Admin -> Restaurant -> [Select location] -> Order -> turn "Offer Delivery" off.
http://imgur.com/a/DQQ4b

Comment: Yes, that I did, so the only button showing now is Collection. However, I still need to 'physically' press the Collection (Pick-up) button for the menu to be clickable. I think it's silly that I need to press a button if there's no other choice.